# JSONArray vs. Array or Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a Question about using JSONArray (java) instead of an Array or ArrayList.

I have a GPS Android Application which stores Locationdata in an JSONArray, because the Database I use, stores everything as JSON Objects. Like this:

```
public void doInJSON(double lat, double lng) throws JSONException
{
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(lat);
    array.put(lng);
    gpsdata.put(array); //<--gpsdata is a JSONArray too.
}
```

if I want to use the data in my Code I can do it like that:

```
gpsdata.getJSONArray(0).getDouble(0);
```

would it be faster if I just store this data in an Array or in an ArrayList and just convert the Array or ArrayList into an JSONArray when storing it in Database?

Comment: You should generally not make the design choice based on whether it will be faster. You should make it based on whether it will be clearer and more maintainable. I wouldn't use a JSONArray, or an array, or a List, to store a latitude and a longitude. I would rather use an immutable `Coordinates` class, with well-named attributes (latitude, longitude, rather than [0] and [1]), and potential additional methods allowing to compare coordinates, etc.

Comment: It's not just clearer and maintainable, it's also a lot safer. A list can have any size and violate the property that it should have only two elements for representing coordinates. Plus, it is mutable so inherits all the safety problems associated with mutability. In general, never allow users (including progammers) to do things they shouldn't do or access things they don't need to access. That's why imposing a rigid immutable structure like JB Nizet described is far safer.

Comment: What about the LatLng Class of Android? Should I use it, if I am fine with the methods etc. it brings?